# нажатие на enter в новом созданном input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код на `jQuery` который создает окно чата:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var btn = $('#createChat').click(function() {
    var msg_box = '';
    msg_box += '<div class="msg_box" id="' + $('#createChat').attr('data') + '">';
    msg_box += '<div class="msg_box_header">';
    msg_box += '<div class="user_name pull-left"><h5></h5></div>';
    msg_box += '<div class="box_close pull-right"><a data="' + $('#createChat').attr('data') + '"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>';
    msg_box += '</div>';
    msg_box += '<div class="msg_box_wrapper"></div>';
    msg_box += '<div class="msg_box_footer">';
    msg_box += '<input type="text" id="send_message" name="send_message" />';
    msg_box += '</div>';
    msg_box += '</div>';

    var aUserMsgCount = $('.users_msg_block').children('a[data="' + $('#createChat').attr('data') + '"]').length;
    if (aUserMsgCount < 1) {
      $('.users_msg_block').prepend('<a data="' + $('#createChat').attr('data') + '" class="new_msg_user"><img src="/images/icons/users/consultation_filled-32.png" alt="" title="" /></a>');
      $('.msg_block').after(msg_box);

      $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=ajax/getUserName',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
          id_author: $('#createChat').attr('data')
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
          $('.user_name h5').text(result.name);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  //тут я пытаюсь отправить сообщение нажатием на кнопку enter, **не работает**
  $('.msg_block').on('keydown', '#send_message', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      // можете делать все что угодно со значением текстового поля 
      alert($(this).val());
    }
  });

  //а эта часть должна закрывать окошко чата, **так же не работает**
  $('.box_close a').click(function() {
    var user = $(this).attr('data');
    $('#' + user).fadeOut(1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="msg_block">
  <div class="users_msg_block"></div>
  <div class="msg_bnt_active">
    <a href="" class=""><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

дело в то что это окно чата создается динамически когда страница полностью загружена после нажатия на кнопку, окно появляется, но вот не получается с отправкой по нажатию на enter и с закрытием окна.

Comment: Вы вешаете хендлеры в тот момент, когда никакого окна еще нету, даже когда вы пытаетесь сделать делегирование на ентер, то елемента с класом `msg_block` еще нету. Как вариант хендлеры переместить внутрь клика по `createChat`

Comment: И еще вы делегируете на елемент `msg_block`, а `$('.msg_block').after(msg_box);` вставляете после него, а не в него.

Comment: msg_block есть в разметке html

Comment: почитайте мой новый коментарий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот упрощенный пример, как ето может работать (с вашей разметкой):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var btn = $('#createChat').click(function() {
    var msg_box = '';
    msg_box += '<div class="msg_box" id="' + $('#createChat').attr('data') + '">';
    msg_box += '<div class="msg_box_header">';
    msg_box += '<div class="user_name pull-left"><h5></h5></div>';
    msg_box += '<div class="box_close pull-right"><a data="' + $('#createChat').attr('data') + '"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>';
    msg_box += '</div>';
    msg_box += '<div class="msg_box_wrapper"></div>';
    msg_box += '<div class="msg_box_footer">';
    msg_box += '<input type="text" id="send_message" name="send_message" />';
    msg_box += '</div>';
    msg_box += '</div>';

    var aUserMsgCount = $('.users_msg_block').children('a[data="' + $('#createChat').attr('data') + '"]').length;

    if (aUserMsgCount < 1) {
      $('.users_msg_block').prepend('<a data="' + $('#createChat').attr('data') + '" class="new_msg_user"><img src="/images/icons/users/consultation_filled-32.png" alt="consultation_filled" title="" /></a>');
      $('.msg_block').after(msg_box);
    }

    $('.msg_box').on('keydown', '#send_message', function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        console.log($(this).val());
      }
    });

    $('.box_close a').click(function() {
      var user = $(this).attr('data');
      $('#' + user).fadeOut(1000);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="createChat" value="+" data="qqq" />

<div class="msg_block">
  <div class="users_msg_block"></div>
  <div class="msg_bnt_active">
    <a href="" class=""><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, помогли!